# Python script with date input

Tags: python, date, input

So I have a script that takes data every 30 seconds for an indefinite amount of time. It saves the data to a text file that is easily read by another program that I can run on another desktop.

Ideally what I would want is a simple user interface where I can input a data, or just a simple string by using a text box or even a drop down menu. Here's the part of my code where the date would go:

```
today = datetime.date.today()

date = str(today)

test = open('[B20] ' + date + "-Temp_Press_Data.txt")

test = test.read()
```

Right now, it just grabs today's date and makes the graph from today's data collected so far. But I can also do this if I wanted to graph the data from yesterday:

```
today = '2015-04-29'

date = str(today)

test = open('[B20] ' + date + "-Temp_Press_Data.txt")

test = test.read()
```

What's the best way to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using the terminal as your "user interface", then the built-in raw_input is a simple solution.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

so:

```
input = raw_input("Enter date in format YYYY-MM-DD:")
test = open('[B20] ' + input + "-Temp_Press_Data.txt")
test = test.read()
```

Your user would run the program from the terminal, and receive the prompt:

```
"Enter date in format YYYY-MM-DD:"
```

And they would type in the date.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [timedelta object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)

date = str(yesterday)

test = open('[B20] ' + date + "-Temp_Press_Data.txt")

test = test.read()
```